# add values in a textarea using a add button & it should be displayed in other textarea appended in a new row

Tags: javascript, html

How to add values in a textarea using a add button & that values should be displayed in other textarea using HTML5

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js">
jQuery('#constraint_btn').click(function(){ 
    var newVal = jQuery('#consEditor_txtarea').attr('value');
    jQuery('#new_html').show();
    jQuery('#new_consEditor_txtarea').attr('value',newVal);
});
</script>

<table>
        <tr>
            <td valign="top"><label>Constarint Editor </label></td>
            <td><textarea id="consEditor_txtarea"></textarea></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td><input type="button" name="" id="constraint_btn" value="Add Constraint" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="new_html">
            <td><label>Added Constraints </label></td>
            <td><textarea id="new_consEditor_txtarea"></textarea></td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Comment: The text entered in constraint_btn has to displayed in new_consEditor_txtarea which is not happening

Comment: For starters you need to change your script tags from `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js">` to `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script><script>`

Comment: Hi i am not getting you, what is the mistake i did, i am new to UI

Comment: Please update the question with what you mean "appended in a new row"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You need to close the script tags with the src and start a new script tag - if there is a src attribute, then you cannot have content inside the script
- You need https (and preferably update the jquery to a newer version) in the jQuery source
- You did not call the fields the same in the code as in the HTML
- You need to execute the code after the page has loaded or the fields rendered - here I wrapped in the `$(function() {})` load event handler

```css
#new_html {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(function() {
    $('#constraint_btn').click(function() {
      let oldVal = $('#consEditor_txtarea').val().trim();
      let newVal = $('#new_consEditor_txtarea').val().trim();
      const vals = newVal.split("\n").filter(item => item);
      if (oldVal) vals.push(oldVal);
      $('#consEditor_txtarea').val(""); // remove 
      $('#new_html').show();
      $('#new_consEditor_txtarea').val(vals.join("\n"));
    });
  });
</script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td valign="top"><label>Constraint Editor </label></td>
    <td><textarea id="consEditor_txtarea"></textarea></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><input type="button" name="" id="constraint_btn" value="Add Constraint" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="new_html">
    <td><label>Added Constraints </label></td>
    <td><textarea id="new_consEditor_txtarea"></textarea></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```